# IPhone autoreleasing a returned NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, memory-management, return, autorelease

I'm still relatively new to iPhone development but thought I understood the basic principals of memory management.  I have a class method that returns an NSMutableArray, I'm calling alloc and init on the object therefore know I'm responsible for releasing it. However because I'm returning the array I assumed I was supposed to use autorelease when creating the object instead of releasing it.

```
+(NSMutableArray *)getStations:(int)stationType {

if(database == nil){
    [self openDataBase];
}

// Create a temporary array to hold the returned objects
NSMutableArray *holder = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

// Check if the statement has been defined
if(select4 == nil) {

    const char *sql = "SELECT station_id, station_name, AVG(test_percent) FROM stations LEFT JOIN tests USING (station_id) WHERE station_type = ? GROUP BY station_id ORDER BY station_name ASC";

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &select4, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Error while creating detail view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}

sqlite3_bind_int(select4, 1, stationType);

// Check if the statement executed correctly
while(sqlite3_step(select4) == SQLITE_ROW) {

    NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(select4, 0);
    Tests *station = [[Tests alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
    station.station_name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select4, 1)];
    station.average_score = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqlite3_column_double(select4, 2)];

    [holder addObject:station];
    [station release];
}

// Reset the detail statement.
sqlite3_reset(select4);

// Return the holder array
return holder;
}
```

There's the basic code - XCode no longer indicates a potential memory leak but it crashes everytime that code executes saying message sent to deallocated instance. Any help would be appreciated I've spent ages googling and can't see what's wrong with the code. I did find this thread but it doesn't appear to be the answer to my question - [crash happens when NSMutableArray is returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452959/crash-happens-when-nsmutablearray-is-returned)

Comment: It crashes inside this method or after this method?

Comment: Tell us about the crash -- where does it happen and what error message is displayed in the console? What does the code calling this method look like?

Comment: After this method, when the table view calls count on the returned array - but if I remove autorelease it works fine (except for the 'potential memory leak' warning. The error message is: -[__NSArrayM count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5d75a00

Comment: @user734971: If you remove `autorelease` from the initialization and use `return [holder autorelease];`, does the crash still occur?

Comment: @EvanMulawski yes I tried that and the crash still occurs.

Comment: @user734971: Could you post the code snippet that performs the call of `getStations:`?

Comment: Pls, give code of the method where you do the count.

Comment: you should use returned array right away, inside selector that calls `getStations:`. if you want to store it for later use (for example, get the array in `viewDidLoad:` method and then use in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`) make sure to retain returned value

Comment: autoreleased objects need to be retained in order to keep them. The caller of this function might need to retain the returned object (depends on what it's doing).

Comment: Ok so I think that's it fixed - originally in my view controller's viewDidLoad method I just had: stationList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[Tests getStations:station_type]]; I didn't realise I had to retain this value as well. If I call retain on the next line (which fixes the problem) do I not need to release it at any point?

Comment: Of course you need to release it. Any object you retain, or copy needs to be appropriately released. If you make it a property in your header, you can release it in your dealloc. That is if it's scope is larger than the one method.

Comment: But it is already released in my dealloc method because it's an instance method that calls alloc and init - but if I have to call retain again after I return it from my model class surely I need to release it? Sorry if this is a dumb question my experience prior to these last 3 months was only in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted appears to be managing memory correctly – you've got a one-to-one relationship between retains and (auto)releases, and you're making a textbook use of autorelease – so the problem is *probably* that the code calling this method needs to `retain` the resulting array before the autorelease pool kicks in and yanks the rug out from under you.

If your code is assigning the NSMutableArray to an ivar you've declared with `@property`, that ivar needs to be declared as

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *myStations;
```

If you're doing something else to store the array, you may need to call `[myStations retain]`. Your table view code will also need to release the array, probably in its `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the returned `NSMutableArray` as a data source to fill in rows in a table view, then you're going to need to retain it in your `UITableView` class (or your `UITableViewDataSource` delegate class). It's going to be called repeatedly whenever the view is scrolled or otherwise needs updating.

Easiest thing to do is make it a retained property in that class.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Tests * stationArray;
```

Then, say, if you want to get your data in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.stationArray = [self getStations: self.stationID]; // property retains
```

Access it in `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
return self.stationArray.count;
```

Access it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
Tests *station = [self.stationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And, of course, in dealloc...

```
[stationArray release];
```

The autorelease in the method is correct (not an init or copy method), but the class will need to retain it if it wants to use it later on, after the current event.